# How do I e2e test axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm new to node.js

I have a basic request logic using axios in my node.js app.

```
axios.get('https://www.github.com');
```

I want to validate the response information (status, body, headers).

How can i validate it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can using [jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/getting-started).

The below code validate response status code.

```
it('Test request check github status code.', async done => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://www.github.com');
  expect(response.status).toBe(200);
  done();
});
```

Run the test code and you'll see the following success message.

```
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.374s
Ran all test suites.
```

Comment: I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'get')` for this example (with `import axios from 'axios'`), any idea why?

Comment: ok, nevermind, I had to add `tsconfig.json` with `{ "compilerOptions": { "esModuleInterop": true } }` to make this work